# Howto show a model from the front, top, right, left, bottom, rear in VTK?

Tags: java, vtk

I want to create a VTK-Viewer and want realize some buttons that automaticly rotate the camera so I look on the model from the front, top, right, left, botton or rear. Has somebody a code snippit in C/C++ or better in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/vtkCamera

The most important lines are:

```
camera->SetPosition(0, 0, 20);
camera->SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0);
```

There's also another parameter called ViewUp (SetViewUp, GetViewUp) which sets the direction that the camera thinks of as "up". With these three, you can effectively show any view of the object that you want.

You may also want to use ResetCamera() on the renderer to zoom out and show the whole object.